# How should I construct a regex match for a various strings within repeated delimiters?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string formatted as:

> GENESIS 1:1 In the beginning God created the heavens ...
> the ground. 2:7 And the LORD ...
> I buried Leah. 49:32 The purchase of the field and of the cave ...
> and he was put in a coffin in Egypt. EXODUS 1:1 Now these are the names ...

Using only one regular expression, I want to match as **groups**:

1. the **book names**
2. the **chapter numbers** (as above 1, 2, 49, 1)
3. the **verse numbers** (as above 1, 7, 32, 1)
4. the **verses** themselves

   - Take the first as example:

   > (GENESIS)*g1* (1)*g2*:(1)*g3* (In the beginning God created the heavens ...)*g4*

This requires that I individually match everything within number-pair colons, while retaining my other groups, and with the limitation of fixed length lookaheads / lookbehinds. That last part specifically is what is proving difficult.

My expression up to now is `(%(BOOK1)s) (\d+):(\d+)\s?(.+?)\s?(?=\d|%(BOOK2)s|$)`, where BOOK1 and BOOK2 change as they iterate through a predetermined list. `$` appears because the very last book will not have a BOOK2 after it. I call re.finditer() on this expression over the whole string and then I iterate through the match object to produce my groups.

The functional part of my expression is currently `(\d+):(\d+)\s?(.+?)\s?(?=\d|%(BOOK2)s|$)`, but by itself this in effect treats GENESIS as BOOK1 always, and matches everything from just after `^` to whatever BOOK2 may be.

Alternatively, keeping my full expression `(%(BOOK1)s) (\d+):(\d+)\s?(.+?)\s?(?=\d|%(BOOK2)s|$)` as is will only return the very first desired match.

I get the sense that some of my greedy / non-greedy terms are malformed, or that I could better use leading / trailing expressions. Any feedback will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably reveal what `BOOK1` and `BOOK2` iterate over. The solution I would propose would be to inline them into the regex if at all possible, and then just `findall`. Getting multiple matches from multiple attempts will be hard to sort out. But of course this might not be feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be making use of the [Python PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and use the `\G` anchor.

Capturing group 1 contains the name of the book and the numbers for the chapter and verse and the verse that follows are in group 2, 3 and 4.

Looping the result, you can check for the presence of the groups.

```
\b(?:([A-Z]{2,})(?= \d+:\d)|\G(?!^))(?:(\d+):(\d+))?\s*((?:[^\dA-Z]+|\d++(?!:\d)|[A-Z](?![A-Z]+ \d+:\d))*)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `([A-Z]{2,})(?= \d+:\d)` Capture **group 1**, match 2 or more uppercase chars and assert what is directly at the right is a space, 1+ digits `:` and a digit
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(\d+):(\d+)` Capture 1 or more digits in **group 2** and **group 3**
- `)?\s*` Close group and make it optional and match optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 4**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^\dA-Z]+` Match 1+ times any char except a digit or A-Z
    - `|` Or
    - `\d++(?!:\d)` Match 1+ digits in a possessive way and assert what is at the right is not `:` followed by a digit
    - `|` Or
    - `[A-Z](?![A-Z]+ \d+:\d)` Match a char A-Z and assert what is directly at the right is not 1+ chars A-Z, space, 1+ digits `:` and a digit
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group 4

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6eB3jx/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##fVHrS8MwEP/ev@Lsp8TNwjZBLIzhY4yBTPCFaBWy9toGbVLS1Ae6v31e0vpBBY/S5O73uORSv9tSq8l2K6taGwsGC3wLglpYi0bBFEyYrNksZvdHe3cPH@PhhrPZFJJsECcZ/0wWbLbzyLljUI13fz5Lml1GtfvHJHO6wSeVB0T1Im9FiV8H3158l4dBQx1ZuJiv5pfLSxjFI1gqsCXCGguplFQFLHQGqUFhMfNIieIFVQNRFPm8MLpVWQTj@ACOVMc5O7849YQlrFsjSXmGooxg/zCejOGKGHVr0lI0CDr3ilzicwaC9H0hpS7ewtUofxUNiSxIBQJSnee0oW9evNc2gvnt@el1d4GVfnUGZC0MeislKvTnTVTIg0rYlGA3ajf7iIwyScNn/RsMoeFBkGsDnrlqq2G3c@1QtRUamgXrbYhthbHTEY8DoJA5dFDk5lKzEe8BF7WRyrI8PNb6yZ8qho@f5A0d8Cc73Ps3ej4@N/i3z0kparoSrMyvRmO@SdQNGhrSH2ziMPdELw7/Be47MOTb7Rc)

For example

```
import regex

pattern = r"\b(?:([A-Z]{2,})(?= \d+:\d)|\G(?!^))(?:(\d+):(\d+))?\s*((?:[^\dA-Z]+|\d++(?!:\d)|[A-Z](?![A-Z]+ \d+:\d))*)"
s = ("GENESIS 1:1 In the beginning God created the heavens ... the ground. 2:7 And the LORD ... I buried Leah. 49:32 The purchase of the field and of the cave ... and he was put in a coffin in Egypt. EXODUS 1:1 Now these are the names ...\n")
matches = regex.finditer(pattern, s)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    if (match.group(1)):
        print(f"Book name: {match.group(1)}")
        print("------------------------------")
    else:
        print(f"Chapter Nr: {match.group(2)}\nVerse Nr: {match.group(3)}\nThe verse: {match.group(4)}\n")
```

Output

```
Book name: GENESIS
------------------------------
Chapter Nr: 1
Verse Nr: 1
The verse: In the beginning God created the heavens ... the ground. 

Chapter Nr: 2
Verse Nr: 7
The verse: And the LORD ... I buried Leah. 

Chapter Nr: 49
Verse Nr: 32
The verse: The purchase of the field and of the cave ... and he was put in a coffin in Egypt. 

Book name: EXODUS
------------------------------
Chapter Nr: 1
Verse Nr: 1
The verse: Now these are the names ...
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I need to implement using pure python, so I'm going to try to avoid PyPi regex for now. So to produce similar results in re, I have  ```(?:([A-Z]{2,})(?= \d+:\d)|(?!^))(?:(\d+):(\d+))?\s*((?:[^\dA-Z]+|\d+(?!:\d)|[A-Z](?![A-Z]+ \d+:\d))*)```. A test case that breaks this ```s = "GENESIS 1:1 In the beginning God created the heavens ... the ground. 2:7 And the LORD 2:8 ..."```, which outputs the same as above, but with the additional ```Book name: LORD, Chapter Nr: 2, Verse Nr: 8, The verse: ...```, plus the loss of LORD as part of the prior verse. This will be an issue.

Comment: Also note, despite the ```\d+``` in **group 2**, I'm only capturing the last digit before the colon

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution in pure python with `re`. Thanks to the above response, I was able to get on the right track. Turns out that wrench I was trying to throw in by testing `LORD 2:8 ...` wasn't actually an issue since non-title capitals never occur before digits that way without punctuation between `[A-Z]` and `\d` in the full string.

Using the same example with the derived pattern:

```
import re

pattern = r"(?:([A-Z]{2,})(?= \d+:\d)|(?!^))(?:(\d+):(\d+))?\s*((?:[^\dA-Z]+(?!:\d)|[A-Z](?![A-Z]+ \d+:\d))+)"
s = ("GENESIS 1:1 In the beginning God created the heavens ... the ground. 2:7 And the LORD ... I buried Leah. 49:32 The purchase of the field and of the cave ... and he was put in a coffin in Egypt. EXODUS 1:1 Now these are the names ...\n")
match = re.finditer(pattern, s)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    if (match.group(1)):
        print(f"Book name: {match.group(1)}")
        print("------------------------------")
    else:
        print(f"Chapter Nr: {match.group(2)}\nVerse Nr: {match.group(3)}\nThe verse: {match.group(4)}\n")
```

As with `regex`, the Output is:

```
Book name: GENESIS
------------------------------
Chapter Nr: 1
Verse Nr: 1
The verse: In the beginning God created the heavens ... the ground.

Chapter Nr: 2
Verse Nr: 7
The verse: And the LORD ... I buried Leah.

Chapter Nr: 49
Verse Nr: 32
The verse: The purchase of the field and of the cave ... and he was put in a coffin in Egypt.

Book name: EXODUS
------------------------------
Chapter Nr: 1
Verse Nr: 1
The verse: Now these are the names ...
```